If python input a value in an empty cell, can I get the style applied to that row or col?

As in the attached image, I selected the entire column and put the color.
After that, I tried to enter values in a specific column using Python openpyxl, but Style was not applied.
I tried various methods, but all failed.
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_path = 'test.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

sheet['C1'] = 'Your Data Here'

workbook.save(file_path)
workbook.close()

I tried to extract the style of the column like the attached source but failed.
import openpyxl

# Load the workbook and select the active worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.active

# Select the specific column (e.g., column 'B')
column_letter = 'B'
column_cells = worksheet[column_letter]

# Function to get the style of a cell
def get_cell_style(cell):
    return {
        'font': cell.font,
        'fill': cell.fill,
        'border': cell.border,
        'alignment': cell.alignment,
        'number_format': cell.number_format,
        'protection': cell.protection,
    }

# Extract styles of all cells in the column
column_styles = {cell.coordinate: get_cell_style(cell) for cell in column_cells}

# Print the styles
for cell, style in column_styles.items():
    print(f"Cell {cell} styles:")
    for attr, value in style.items():
        print(f"  {attr}: {value}")


In what way(s) did it fail?

If you fill a whole row or column with a colour then the colour is applied differently than if you fill just a range of cells. When filling the whole row or column the colour is applied to the row or column property and not to the individual cells. So looking at the cell for the fill colour will return no colour value... Try changing your fill to say just the first 10 rows in each column (or every row except the last) and you will get the colour for each cell returned.

This is also why your writing a value in the cell the fill is lost where it would be expected to be retained. Again if you don't fill the whole column the fill will not be changed when you write a value to it.

As for the rest of your 'styles'. That would be default cell values since there are no apparent font, border, alignment or number format applied to the cell 'B1'

If you do want to Fill the whole column and obtain the colour value then you'd need to look at the 'column_dimensions' for the worksheet.
Example, the following code would print out the Fill RGB value for each column A - C.
for column, column_properties in worksheet.column_dimensions.items():
    print(f"Column {column} Fill Colour: {column_properties.fill.fgColor.rgb}")

Assuming they were Red/Green/Blue you'd get
Column A Fill Colour: FFFF0000
Column B Fill Colour: FF00FF00
Column C Fill Colour: FF0000FF


Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem.
Based on what you told me, I wrote the source below.
I checked the empty cell and made it apply the style applied to the entire row or col.

def apply_style_if_empty(worksheet, cell):
    column = cell.column_letter
    row = cell.row
    column_properties = worksheet.column_dimensions.get(column, None)
    row_properties = worksheet.row_dimensions.get(row, None)

    # Check if the cell is empty
    if cell.value is None:
        # Apply style from column_dimensions if available
        if column_properties:
            if column_properties.fill:
                cell.fill = copy.copy(column_properties.fill)
            if column_properties.font:
                cell.font = copy.copy(column_properties.font)
            if column_properties.alignment:
                cell.alignment = copy.copy(column_properties.alignment)
            if column_properties.number_format:
                cell.number_format = copy.copy(column_properties.number_format)
        # If column_properties is None or has no style, apply from row_dimensions if available
        if row_properties:
            if row_properties.fill:
                cell.fill = copy.copy(row_properties.fill)
            if row_properties.font:
                cell.font = copy.copy(row_properties.font)
            if row_properties.alignment:
                cell.alignment = copy.copy(row_properties.alignment)
            if row_properties.number_format:
                cell.number_format = copy.copy(row_properties.number_format)

